# Prepopulate dynaform textbox(es)

Tags: processmaker

I have a variable from a previous step which I want to use to prepopulate textboxes in a dynaform via an SQL query to an external database. How can I do this? Can anyone provide me with an example XML field ... or do I have to use a trigger?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find material [on this](http://wiki.processmaker.com/index.php/Database_Connections) link, when you create the field to populate it with the sql statement choose the connection you made and then write the sql on the box below.

The final xml will be something like>

```
 <MyDropdown type="dropdown" required="0" readonly="0" savelabel="0"
   mode="edit" options="Array" sqlconnection="dbarray">
   SELECT CONTACT_ID, CONTACT_NAME FROM CONTACTS
   <en>Select Contact</en>
 </MyDropdown>
```

Regards.